# css not working in certain section of master page but working in separate web form asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I have created a master page with a basic login page and applied css in it. But i get styles only for background and footer only, other divs does not get applied.
[image]

so i decided to create a web form and copied it without contentplaceholder it works
[image]

My css code:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0N6SzL5p

My css working Web form code:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QrvttGqN

Master page code:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=C2LH0SrE

And its content login page:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GdQpWnVX

I'm a newbie in asp and i'm not **trolling.**
If it is a silly mistake please point it out and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stylesheet, the problem with the master page was that you should have a wrapper `<div>` that surrounds all of your nested elements.

A lot of your `<div id="xx">` elements should be changed to `<div class="xx">` as your stylesheet is CSS class definitions. e.g.

**From:**

```
<div id="top" runat="server">
```

and..

```
<div id="mainpage" runat="server">
```

and..

**To:**

```
<div class="top">
```

and..

```
<div class="mainpage">
```

and..

```
<div class="footer">
```

### Complete Master Page Changes

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Demo.master.cs" Inherits="UI.Master.Demo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link href="../CSS/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="top">
                <div class="topmiddle">
                    <div class="logreg" id="login_reg" runat="server">
                        <a href="~/My_Account/Demo_login.aspx" class="toptext" runat="server">Login</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <a href="~/My_Account/Demo_Register.aspx" class="toptext" runat="server">Register</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userlog" id="user_logout" runat="server" visible="false">
                        Welcome<asp:Label ID="username" runat="server">!</asp:Label>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <a id="A3" href="Logout.aspx" class="atypesty" runat="server">LogOUT</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainpage">
                <table class="maintable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../Images/logo.jpg" class="logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="menucenter">
                            <ul id="Nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="Navprofile" runat="server">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnbtn_Profile" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="demo" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>All words, images and code copyright ©2014 demo.com. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is almost 1am will check tomo and reply

Comment: @Amjath Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See here for a full explanation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: No offence bro but the above didn't fix the issue. I had some issue with css which does the trick. So tell me what to do. I have been marking my previous question as answered if it helped me.

Comment: None taken, if you get an answer on SO and it doesn't work you need to let us know so we can dig in to it for you.. Also, if you fix it yourself you should post it as an answer to your own question. P.S. I'm very curious to see what the problem was as both CSS are exactly the same.

Comment: Honestly I dont what the issue is. I did my Master Page and few CSS again it got fixed http://imgur.com/RL9pabJ
Help me what to do

Comment: I guess it is something to do with using position in div, So I avoided using position for divs in css
New Master Code
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k7m4VGtE
New CSS Code
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UeKgxPsz

Comment: thank you I learnrt the same use class instead of id name in div